# Disabling line numbers in section headers

Tags: line-numbering

I'm using the lineno package to number lines in a document. By default, lineno attempts to number everything, including section headers. I would like disable line numbering on section headers, preferably in an automated way so I don't need to manually edit every section header in my document.

The [lineno manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lineno/ulineno.pdf) provides the following ways to disable line numbering:

```
\nolinenumbers
... text ...
\linenumbers

\begin{nolinenumbers}
... text ...
\end{nolinenumbers}
```

This works fine except I need to manually add this code around every `\section{...}` call in my document.

Presumably I could `\renewcommand{\section}` to do this automatically, but I am not sure of the Right Way (TM) to do this. The following naive code appears to work, but I am not convinced that I won't trip over some nasty edge case by doing this. Among other things, I'll need to redefine `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` in addition to `\section` for this to work in general.

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\nolinenumbers \oldsection{#1} \linenumbers}
```

Is there a more robust and/or elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using any packages that could affect sectional units/headers (like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), or [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), or...)?

Comment: I'm not using any of those (and do not expect to), although I would be willing to consider using one if it would make solving the problem easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not using any special packages, the following would be sufficient:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,lineno}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@startsection}{\@ifstar}{\nolinenumbers\@ifstar}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@xsect}{\ignorespaces}{\linenumbers\ignorespaces}{}{}
\makeatother
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\section{A section} \lipsum[2]
\subsection{Another section} \lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{Final section} \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

There are two patches applied with the aid of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

- The first inserts `\nolinenumbers` as part of `\@startsection` - called just after `\par` is issued to ensure there is no line numbers in the sectional title line;
- The second inserts `\linenumbers` just after the sectional title has been set.

The specific location of these insertions will allow for unnumbered sectional units of all types (starred or not), although the effect will not be visible in some instances (like `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`, by default), since run-in sections have text immediately following the title.

Comment: I'm running into an error when I try to compile this on overleaf. I'm not sure what is causing it.
Here is the part of my preamble where I call the `\lineno` package.
`\usepackage[pagewise]{etoolbox,lineno}
\patchcmd{\@startsection}{\@ifstar}{\nolinenumbers\@ifstar}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@xsect}{\ignorespaces}{\linenumbers\ignorespaces}{}{}
\makeatother
\linenumbers\relax`

The error I'm getting is "Option clash package for etoolbox" and "Missing \begin{document}" but it's not missing.

I also added the global option pagewise to the documentclass but that didn't work either.

Comment: @WnGatRC456: Try with `\usepackage{etoolbox}\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}`.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. I'll make a separate question to try and get this sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Some supplements to Werner's great answer, in case you are using `titlesec`, for which Werner's patch does not work.

First, a quick aside of using `\nolinenumbers` and `\linenumbers`. Actually, in my own packages or classes, I usually have the following:

```
\newif\ifLNturnsON
\def\LocallyStopLineNumbers{\LNturnsONfalse%
    \ifLineNumbers\LNturnsONtrue\fi\nolinenumbers}
\def\ResumeLineNumbers{\ifLNturnsON\linenumbers\fi}
```

`\LocallyStopLineNumbers` and `\ResumeLineNumbers` are better than just `\nolinenumbers` and `\linenumbers` in that they detect if the line numbering has already been turned on, so after disabling the line numbers `\ResumeLineNumbers` won't enable it if the user hasn't enabled the line numbering at the time of `\LocallyStopLineNumbers`.

With `titlesec`, you can add `\LocallyStopLineNumbers` to the beginning of the format, and `[\LocallyStopLineNumbers]` to the end. In the following example, I included a complete set of formats that mimic the default styles (the code is copied from documentation of `titlesec`, "*8.2. Standard Classes*"). You can of course modify your own style in the similar way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\newif\ifLNturnsON
\def\LocallyStopLineNumbers{\LNturnsONfalse%
    \ifLineNumbers\LNturnsONtrue\fi\nolinenumbers}
\def\ResumeLineNumbers{\ifLNturnsON\linenumbers\fi}

\makeatletter

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\LocallyStopLineNumbers\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}[\ResumeLineNumbers]
\titleformat{\section}
{\LocallyStopLineNumbers\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[\ResumeLineNumbers]
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\LocallyStopLineNumbers\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}[\ResumeLineNumbers]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\LocallyStopLineNumbers\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[\ResumeLineNumbers]
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\LocallyStopLineNumbers\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}[\ResumeLineNumbers]
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
{\LocallyStopLineNumbers\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}[\ResumeLineNumbers]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}     {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}     {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}   {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}   {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph} {\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}

\makeatother

\linenumbers

\begin{document}
\section{A section} \lipsum[2]
\subsection{Another section} \lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{Final section} \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]